# Is this the largest delta precision achieved in any Physics measurement?

Tags: experimental-physics

Recently I [**read this article**](https://phys.org/news/2017-11-physicists-rapid-bounding-gravity.html#jCp) in Phys.org that states:

#### edit: providing previous precision value

> Over the past few months, physicists have made very rapid progress in
> bounding the speed of gravity using gravitational wave observations.
> Initially, the first LIGO detections of gravitational waves
> constrained the speed of gravity to within 50% of the speed of light.

Then,...

> "...they were able to constrain the difference between the speed of gravity and the speed of light to between -3 x $10^{-15}$ and 7 x $10^{-16}$ times the speed of light. ..."

So has there ever been such a large leap achieved in the precision of any Physics measurement? Also, why is there a minus sign on the three in **-3** x $10^{-15}$?

Comment: I'm guessing there was a negative sign in case the speed of gravity was less than the speed of light.

Comment: The quote you give is not a "jump in precision".  They compared the "speed of gravity" to the "speed of light" and found that they agree to many decimal places.

Comment: The very next sentence says, "The reason for the huge leap in precision is..."

Comment: @GeraldEdgar See my edit.  I am guessing that's what the OP intended to ask about.

Comment: @TheRaidersofLasVegas  The question is not *why* but rather is this the largest delta precision achieved in any physics measurement.